# $Φ_n$ is Euler group, $n> 2$ is an integer, and $m$ the number of solutions of the equation $x^2 = 1$ in the ring $Z_n$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

- Prove

$$\prod_{i ∈ Φ_n} i=(-1)^{\frac{m}{2}}$$

- Then what becomes this identity if $n$ is a prime number?

I know that if $x^2=1$, we pair the number with its inverse modulo $n$ in the product. Otherwise, we pair it up with $−x$. But still don't know how to prove it.

Can please anyone help me with this proof?

Comment: I swear I have seen this question asked before, but I can't find it. I guess it was deleted.

Comment: I do not know, I did not manage to find anything similar @Wojowu

Comment: I'm confused, didn't you just state the proof in the question? If $i^2 \neq 1$, then pair $i$ with it's inverse since $i \neq i^{-1}$. Else, both $i$ and $-i$ satisfy $i^2 = (-i)^2 = 1$ and you can pair $i$ with $-i$ in the product ($i \neq -i$ since $i$ and $n$ share no common factors).